# How can I place a file in a Java application so that both main and test can access it?

Tags: java

I have style sheet file (e.g. `myStyle.xslt`). I am trying to decide where to put this file in my web application so that both src and test can access it. All my source in packages inside `/src` folder and test code in packages inside `/test` folder.

Comment: create a resources folder under the project root, then you can refer to it by "resources/.."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you use Maven.

Place the file in a folder `src/main/resources/<your special place>/myStyle.xslt`.

In your application and in your test you can access the file by

```
// Get the Classloader to load the XSLT
ClassLoader classloader = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
// Get th URL of the file
URL url = classloader.getResource("<your special place>/myStyle.xslt");
// Now you can read it...
InputStream in = url.openStream();
// ...or use it as a file
// ATTATION: This works only if the file is not inside a a JAR, WAR etc.
//           But it works inside your JUnit or TestNG tests and in an exploded WAR
File file = new File(url.toURI());
```

Hope that helps